# Project architecture and its flow?

Tags: .net, asp.net

In my project flow is like this-

C# code behind page  call the business class in which we have declared variables and method for add,delete and call the stored procedure in the same file of business class .Then which architecture is this?

Comment: You mention code-behind files. Is this ASP.NET? WPF?

Answer (score 1):

To disambiguate layers and tiers, have a look at [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jmeier/archive/2008/09/06/layers-and-tiers.aspx).

You could say that you have a 3 or 4-layer architecture, depending on how you look at it, but that is a statement that one can make about many applications.  What are you actually looking for?

To elaborate on the layer , you have:

1. A presentation layer (HTML + JS)
2. A presentation logic layer (Codebehind)
3. Data access layer (business class)
4. Data layer (the actual database)

Unless you are actually doing some further logic in the business class, I wouldn't call it a "business layer".

Comment: A tier is a physical separation. A logical separation is a layer.

Comment: means i am little confuse about that what is my project architeture 2-3 so its 2 layer which i got from pranay answer because my business and data layer is same and one is presentation layer.

Comment: @parnita, as Pete pointed out, a tier usually refers to a physical separation, while a layer refers to a logical separation.  Most of the time, you will have multiple layers in one physical tier.  For example, your codebehind and business class sit on the same server, but are different layers.

Comment: ok i got the answer now Thanks a lot for ur help..Pete and Daniel